# kill multiple process at once works only manually not from inside script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to kill multiple process at the same time. 
Im using this simple for loop to kill the process by PID number.

```
for i in $(ps -ejH | grep omn_bdxtrc|awk '{print $1}'); do kill ${i}; done
```

The loop works fine if I enter it manually in the terminal.
but if I want to us it from inside an file `(*.sh)` it returns this output.

```
/functions.sh: line 231: kill: 25211
25698
27930
8477
5018
16383
13488
2403
10963 18796: arguments must be process or job IDs
```

have tried multiple ways that works manually, but not from the file.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the script just the for loop, as shown above?

Comment: @kabanus no, actually this loop is inside a function. the script does multiple stuffs before. could that be the problem?

Comment: Not sure. I suggest you post your script that reproduced the error (try and make it minimal).

Comment: Do you change the `IFS` environment variable somewhere in the script?

Comment: @GordonDavisson yes :) i actually did that. but that's fixed now! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the PIDs are being passed as a single argument delimited by line breaks, which `kill` does not seem to like.

I would simplify the approach by removing the loop completely and just passing the PIDs to `kill` via `xargs`:

```
ps -ejH | grep omn_bdxtrc | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```

Alternatively (if you don't have or don't want to use `xargs` for some reason), you can keep your current loop and just sanitize the output from awk by changing all possible line breaks to spaces using `tr`:

```
for i in $(ps -ejH | grep omn_bdxtrc | awk '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ' '); do kill ${i}; done
```

But this is not that elegant.

Probably the most elegant solution would be to use `killall`, assuming you know the exact name of the process:

```
killall omn_bdxtrc
```

Or if you don't know the exact name and need to match a part of it:

```
killall --regexp '.*omn_bdxtrc.*'
```

Comment: Hi! you're complete right, the PIDs where passed as a singel argument!
I can use all of the suggestions you gave me. 
Thank you so much for the help!